# Radio buttons from a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, collections, radio-button, slim-lang

I am trying to return a set of radio buttons based on a collection within my database but I am not having much luck.

View code

```
- @merchant_type.each do |mt|
    = form.radio_button mt, mt.name
```

Controller Code

```
def new
    @merchant_type =  MerchantType.all
    @merchant = Merchant.new
    @states = State.form_selector
    @products = Product.order(:name => 'asc')
    @properties = Property.where(property_set_id: 1)
    @merchant.trading_hours.build
  end
```

Error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `#<MerchantType:0x007fd16b55ac50>' for #<Merchant:0x007fd16c481468>):
    6:     p
    7:       b Type
    8:       - @merchant_type.each do |mt|
    9:         = form.radio_button mt, mt.name
  app/views/admin/merchants/_type.html.slim:9:in `block in _app_views_admin_merchants__type_html_slim___3402008222164699688_70268702644260'
  app/views/admin/merchants/_type.html.slim:8:in `_app_views_admin_merchants__type_html_slim___3402008222164699688_70268702644260'
```

Comment: `MerchantType.all` is obviously triggering the error... but I can't infer what might be triggering the error just like that. I assume you are able to run `MerchantType.all` in your rails console right?

Comment: Did you try this "form.radio_button :merchant_type, mt.name"?

Comment: @Jayaprakash no I didn't, and that seems to have worked

Comment: Can I put this as an answer?

Comment: sure can, it has fixed my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
- @merchant_type.each do |mt|
    = form.radio_button :merchant_type, mt.name
```